# Is there any downside to leaving a laptop in Legacy mode instead of UEFI?

Tags: bios, uefi

I had problems installing Windows in UEFI mode on a laptop; and ended up installing it in Legacy mode (DVD bootability issue).

Now that it's installed, ***is there any downside with leaving it in legacy mode***? (instead of going through the effort of researching and making changes to make it UEFI, presumably in MBR2GPT?)

The system will only have one Windows installation, no other OS will be installed. One hard drive with one primary partition. 1TB in size.

Comment: the hard drive is < 2TB?

Comment: @jiggunjer- updated

Comment: @Ramhound - converted to GPT and it seems to be booting SLOWER in UEFI

Comment: If it has an option for pure UEFI mode (not hybrid), enable that option. On recent PCs, that speeds up *a lot.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your boot disk will have to be partitioned as MBR for Windows to boot and as a result the disk itself will be limited to slightly less than 2TB in size.

If your boot disk is 1TB or less this is unlikely to be a serious concern.

You can still have 2TB or larger secondary disks partitioned as GPT, the limitation is only there for the *boot* disk as Windows only supports booting from BIOS+MBR or UEFI+GPT.